# "Unable to connect to remote server" when Connecting to Google's Distance Matrix Service

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm having this problem...I have a web application developed with framework 4.0 that calls a google web service (distance matrix)... like this

```
XPathDocument Doc = new XPathDocument(
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?&origins=" + start +
    "&destinations=" + stop + "&units=metric&sensor=false&language=it");
```

all works fine on my client.. all the problems starts after deploying the app on the web server with IIS ...... I have this error

```
Unable to connect to the remote server
[SocketException (0x274d): Unable to connect to the remote server 173.194.65.95:80]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +305
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) +699

[WebException: Impossibile effettuare la connessione al server remoto.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +7769892
   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy) +160
   System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn) +318
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver) +75
   System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData) +136
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) +0
   System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state) +118
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl() +4996487
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +120
   System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space) +386
   System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(String uri, XmlSpace space) +130

   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +154
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3691
```

If I try to call directly from the web server the web service from the browser....
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?&origins=milano&destinations=roma&units=metric&sensor=false&language=it

..all works fine and I can see the XML document

Comment: Does the server you deploy to have a proxy? Does it have web access? That's the most likely cause.

Comment: Is the 173.194.65.95 being resolved automatically or have you hard-coded that IP address?

Comment: Whenever you see a case of "I can access it from my browser, but not from my application", you should suspect web proxy settings. The browser will be set up to automatically use the correct proxy settings. You application will not.

Comment: Yes I'm behind a proxy....so I think I have to make my request hard-coding in my aspx.cs the proxy address and credentials..... but how? Anyone has an example?

Comment: Could you please help? I also have this situation. Anyone faced with this error before??